# Find relationships by timestamp and proximity to respective lat/long

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm new to python and I have hit a wall with this problem. I have a df with ID's, timestamp and lat /longs. I need to find ID's that were are near each other by location and time. I've tried groupby with pandas, but the output just lumps everything under each unique ID. Is there a way to pair or group ID's by their proximity to each ID's  lat/longs (<50m) and timestamp (<=24hrs). I appreciate any help. Thanks!

| ID | Timestamp | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9269 | 11/23/2021 23:59 | 40.3291824 | -105.656204 |
| 9269 | 11/19/2021 23:59 | 40.32294108 | -105.8062935 |
| 9269 | 11/15/2021 23:59 | 40.13903661 | -105.5979048 |
| 9269 | 11/15/2021 23:39 | 40.3291824 | -105.656204 |
| 7359 | 11/11/2021 23:59 | 40.13903661 | -105.5979048 |
| 7359 | 11/7/2021 23:59 | 40.32294108 | -105.8062935 |
| 7359 | 11/7/2021 23:39 | 40.3291824 | -105.656204 |
| 2259 | 12/6/2021 0:02 | 40.32294108 | -105.8062935 |
| 2259 | 12/2/2021 0:02 | 40.3291824 | -105.656204 |
| 2259 | 11/28/2021 0:02 | 40.13903661 | -105.5979048 |

Comment: You need to start write some code to calculate the distance between the points, and show what you have done so far so we can help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you some steps that you can use to solve your problem.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Creating a 2 dimensional numpy array
data = np.array([[1, 2,3,4,5,1, 2,3,4,5],[10, 20,30,40,50,10, 20,30,40,50],['s.40','s.50','s.40','s.50','s.40','s.50','s.40','s.50','s.40','s.50']])


# Creating pandas dataframe from numpy array
df= pd.DataFrame({'Column1': data[0,:], 'Column2': data[1,:],'Column3': data[2,:]})
```

I create a dataframe from a numpy array.
In your dataframe in Timestamp Column you have data and time you need splint it
and create a new column. You can do it as follow in my example:

```
def split_function(Column3):
    return Column3.split('.')[1]

df['split_column']=df.apply(lambda x: split_function(x.Column3), axis=1)
```

In your case u can use a blank space ' ' to do your split in return Column3.split(' ')[1]
Than u need garante that ur column have the right type so u can use:

```
df['Column1']=pd.to_numeric(df['Column1'])
df['Column2']=pd.to_numeric(df['Column2'])
```

(See also to_datetime() and to_timedelta()

Than u need know how many interval you have, so you can use max and min method to help you find it:

In my example :

```
df['Column1'].max()
df['Column1'].min()

df['Column2'].max()
df['Column2'].min()
```

It will return
5
1
and
50
10

Let supose i want a interval of 25 based on my Column 2,
So i will have 2 groups interval.

Finally i just need select the rows based on a column condition
you can see more info about it here :

[How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

```
list_dataframe_interval=[]

for i in range(2):
    print(i*25)
    print(type(i))

    df1=df.loc[(df['Column2'] >=i*25) & (df['Column1'] >= i*2.5)]
    df2=df1.loc[(i*25+25 >=df1['Column2']) & (i*2.5+2.5>=df1['Column1'])]
    

   
    list_dataframe_interval.append(df2)
```

So you can see the dataframe in this list

list_dataframe_interval[0]

list_dataframe_interval[1]